# Null Autowired Spring Bean (Cassandra Repository) in Service

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on an autowired bean in a service class. The class I'm trying to autowire is a Cassandra Repository.

My main class Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Cassandra configuration CassandraConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.myretail")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "myretail";
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster =
                new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
        cluster.setPort(9042);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping()
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductService productService() {
        return new ProductService();
    }
}
```

My repository (dao) ProductPriceRepository.java

```
public interface ProductPriceRepository extends CassandraRepository<ProductPrice> {

    @Query("select * from productprice where productId = ?0")
    ProductPrice findByProductId(String productId);
}
```

My service class ProductService.java

```
@Path("/product")
@Component
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    ProductPriceRepository productPriceRepository;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Product getTargetProduct(@PathParam("id") String productId) {
        String urlString = "https://api.vendor.com/products/v3/" + productId + "?fields=descriptions&id_type=TCIN&key=43cJWpLjH8Z8oR18KdrZDBKAgLLQKJjz";
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(JsonReader.getExternalJsonResponse(urlString));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setId(productId);
        try {
            JSONObject productCompositeResponse = json.getJSONObject("product_composite_response");
            JSONArray items = productCompositeResponse.getJSONArray("items");
            JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject onlineDescription = item.getJSONObject("online_description");
            product.setName(onlineDescription.getString("value"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ProductPrice productPrice = productPriceRepository.findByProductId(productId);
        product.setProductPrice(productPrice);

        return product;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myretail</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyRetail</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyRetail</name>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hectorclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>my-tomcat</server>
                    <path>/myRetail</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It is my understanding that the annotations should pick up the repository and create the bean based off of the `@EnableCassandraRepositories` annotation. The `@Autowired ProductPriceRepository` in `ProductService.java` is always `null` though when I run this on tomcat. HOWEVER, if I run a junit test against the service call, the bean is properly created, the object is not null, and the tests pass (via `@ContextConfiguration` annotation).

I've looked at a couple different patterns that I thought might help, but none of them have worked. I can't create an implementation of my interface because Cassandra handles that internally and I'm forced to implement the Cassandra methods.

I feel like something is just slightly off with the annotations somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: have you annotated `ProductPriceRepository` with `@Repository` annotation?

Comment: Yes, I had taken it out, but I've added it back in. I also made the dependency changes you mentioned previously (that post looks like it disappeared??) and now I'm getting the error below.

Looks like another dependency error maybe...

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productPriceRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactory$CassandraQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;

Comment: Your service is actually a Jax-RS implementation, which isn't managed by spring but your Jax-RS provider (I suspect Jersey). Without proper integration it doesn't do anything with `@Autowired`. The test works because then it is a spring managed bean and you basically remove the jax-rs part.

Comment: Yep, you're correct, I am using Jersey. Sounds like that means I need the jersey-spring3 dependency added to my pom for that?

Comment: Spring-boot does most of the configurations, please have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-cassandra

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `pom.xml`

For `spring-boot`  Cassandra application, you have to include below dependencies and parent pom in `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```